# Posted date format not reflected

Tags: date, theme-twenty-thirteen

WP3.6, Twenty Thirteen theme

No matter which `Date Format` I choose, the date on actual posts are shown like this:

```
%A %B %e%q, %Y
```

Note that the actual texts look like this; not even the date values (eg. 9/01/2013).
Looking at `content-link.php`, date might be displayed by the following that I suspect is not returning a right value?

```
        <?php twentythirteen_entry_date(); ?>
```

What's wrong? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround by myself. In wp-content/themes/twentythirteen/function.php:

```
function twentythirteen_entry_date( $echo = true ) {
:
    //$date = sprintf( '<span class="date"><a href="%1$s" title="%2$s" rel="bookmark"><time class="entry-date" datetime="%3$s">%4$s</time></a></span>',
    $date = sprintf( '<span class="date"><a href="%1$s" title="%2$s" rel="bookmark"><time class="entry-date" datetime="%3$s">%3$s</time></a></span>',
```

x `%4$s`

o `%3$s`

---

Still, it doesn't seem to reflect the choice of the date-format setting made on `wp`.